# IronPython: Trouble building a WPF ShaderEffect

Tags: wpf, ironpython, shader

I'm trying to build an extensible program where users, among other things, can build their own shader effects.

Google searching got me this far;

```
class Test(ShaderEffect):
    inputProperty = ShaderEffect.RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty("Input", type(Test()), 0)
```

But I still get the error;

> TypeError: cannot access protected
>   member
>   RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty
>   without a python subclass of
>   ShaderEffect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The best source on the net I could find [is linked here](http://ironpython.net/ironpython/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#accessing-protected-members-of-base-types)

Comment: This actually sounds like a bug in that static members aren't being exposed publicly once a base class is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Reflection to access protected memeber of .NET class - you don't have a Python subclass where you can access such member directly.

Try somethink like this (I have't tested it):

```
inputPropertyType = ShaderEffect.GetType().GetMember(
    'RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty',
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
inputProperty = inputPropertyType.GetValue(ShaderEffect, None)
inputProperty("Input", type(Test()), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I didn't know this could be done.

I tried;

class Test(ShaderEffect): pass
inputProperty = Test().GetType().GetMember('RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty', BindingFlags.Static)("Input", type(Test()), 0)

But I am getting the error; MemberInfo[] is not callable?

Comment: My mistake - you have to find out the value. Try the edited version.